# CSS - Frames with bobbly borders

Tags: html, css, canvas, shapes

I would like to do wobbly frames for images and text in a website (if they could move, it would be optimal), but im not sure how to do it. I've been looking into paperjs.org but I'm not sure if I can use it to wrap HTML text with irregular forms.

Do you guys know any library or technique that i could use to do this effect? Or is it maybe impossible in the current status of the web?

[image]

Comment: looks like a normal mask you would use in programs like photoshop. on the web, you can do that with CSS mask. Look at this if it may help: http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/

Comment: nope! That would be a bit more complicated: take a look at this http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/3d/css/ and this http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/css-shaders.html

Comment: still don't know how you can wrap text on it, btw...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple but less then optimal solution would be to post your html content with a z-index of 1 and then place PNG of the background over top of the content with a z-index of 2.

That would allow you to simulate the picture you have posted but wouldn't be able to add any animation of the content shape. Though you could have the background pan to the left or right(simulating the effect of looking through a window, as you walk to the left or right).

If you wanted to create the same effect but with the possibility of animating the shapes you would probably want to use [HTML5 Canvas](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-canvas-rect.php), but how exactly that would be done is beyond me.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't be able to select the text with this method. Thanks for your idea.

Comment: You could place the text on top with a z-index of 3 and still be able to highlight it.